# Python equivalent to PHP Post

Tags: php, python

I am working with legacy system, and the previous programmer has gone. Here is the test he left and I have no idea how to imitate his test using Python.

Here is `test.php`

```
var tHost = "10.1.10.123";
var tExiname = "CloudHM TEST123";
var tIncname = "INC012345";
var tHWname = "aa 1111 0";
var tHwattr = "all";
var tStatus = 0;
var tCteatedat = "2016-05-23 12:20:42";
var d = new Date,
tUpdateat = [d.getFullYear(),
             d.getMonth()+1,
             d.getDate()].join('-')+' '+
          [d.getHours(),
           d.getMinutes(),
           d.getSeconds()].join(':');
var arr =  [{ host: tHost, host_name: tExiname, component_type: tHWname, component_status: tStatus, incident_created: tUpdateat }];
var arr2 =JSON.stringify(arr)
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://customer.beenets.net/api/cloudhm/api.php' ,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { params: arr2 },
    success: function(msg) {
        //ShowOutput(msg);
        alert(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4));
    }
})
```

I had tried this. Response is `200`, but PHP server read no payload

```
notification_data = [{
            "host": i.host,
            "host_name": i.host_name,
            "incident_created": i.incident_created,
            "component_type": i.component_type,
            "component_status": i.component_status
        }]
        response = requests.post(NOC_BEENETS_URL, data=json.dumps(notification_data))
```

Then I try put `params` key in front of it

```
notification_data = [{
    "params":{
        "host": i.host,
        "host_name": i.host_name,
        "incident_created": i.incident_created,
        "component_type": i.component_type,
        "component_status": i.component_status
    }
}]
response = requests.post(NOC_BEENETS_URL, data=json.dumps(notification_data))
```

Server return me 200 and read no payload again.

Comment: in `test.php` you have JavaScript code, not PHP code - so you don't need PHP to run it :)

Comment: I think you need `data={"params":json.dumps(...)}`

Comment: @furas Give me a second. It is remote editing

Comment: @furas PHP legacy can read my payload now. Thank you `furas` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:

```
notification_data = [{
        "host": i.host,
        "host_name": i.host_name,
        "incident_created": i.incident_created,
        "component_type": i.component_type,
        "component_status": i.component_status
    }]
r = requests.post(NOC_BEENETS_URL, data = {'params': json.dumps(notification_data)})
```

Comment: Does not work. And it response `200` to me. To confirm that I have payload here is `pdb` (Pdb) response.content
'{"response_data":{"host":"10.0.34.1","component_status":"0","host_name":"LMD718","component_type":"server","incident_created":"2016-10-03 17:59:45"},"response_datetime":"2016-10-12 16:18:18"}'

Comment: Thank you it works. I just found your edited after `furas` comment